# How to display a selected post on a comments form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am working on a project in which a user can post a video and comment on other people's videos such as instagram.

The comments page have 3 parts, a form that uploads a comment, a form that displays the comments.

And finally the video that users select to comment on (which is not displaying).

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=160)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.post.title, str(self.user.username))

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='clips', null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='imageuser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='username')
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=None, blank=True, related_name='liked')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.text)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('comments', args=[self.pk])
```

views.py

```
def comments(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            content = request.POST.get('content')
            comment = Comment.objects.create(post=post, user=request.user, content=content)
            comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())

    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    context2 = {
        "comments": comments,
        "comment_form": comment_form,

    }
    return render(request, 'comments.html', context2)
```

comments.html

```
<div class="post-container">
  <video class="video" width='400'>
    <source src='{{ video.url }}' type='video/mp4'>
  </video>
</div>
<div class="comment-container">
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{comment_form.as_p}}
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    {% else %}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"disabled>
    {% endif %}
  </form>
  <div class="main-comment-section">
    {{ comments.count }}
    {% for comment in comments %}
      <blockquote class="blockquote">
        <p class="mb-0">{{ comment.content }}</p>
        <footer class="blockquote-footer">by <cite title="Source Title">{{ comment.user }}</cite></footer>
      </blockquote>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Any questions please let me know;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this to your context dictionary `"post": post` and remove `"comments": comments,` from the context

Then in your template you can loop through comments like

```
{% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
  <blockquote class="blockquote">
    <p class="mb-0">{{ comment.content }}</p>
    <footer class="blockquote-footer">by <cite title="Source Title">{{ comment.user }}</cite></footer>
  </blockquote>
{% endfor %}
```

Then for the video do

```
<video class="video" width='400'>
  <source src='{{ post.video.url }}' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

Also, it's needless to call `comment.save()` when you're using `Comment.objects.create()` method. The `create()` method calls the `save()`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that video is media file(like file field , image etc.) and you have add all those things which you add for an media field i.e. MEDIA_URL, MEDIA_ROOT, urls and encryption
Make sure you have maintained the media file settings. In your settings.py file:

````
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media/")```
Then in your main urls.py:

```urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ... ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
````

Also make sure you add  `enctype="multipart/form-data` in form tag in your template.

For more info., look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/